# Solr multivalue field search not including a specific value

Tags: solr

Need to search on a multivalued field in Sorl. Field name is "nodeclass" ,possible values are "pone", "bone" ,"hone" , "sone"and "node".

I want to get all docs which doesent contain "pone" value.

`*:* query returns ---> 236636 docs`
`nodeclass:pone returns ---->  1643 docs`
`nodeclass:not(pone) returns ----> 2460 docs`

all docs contains `nodeclass` field. here my guess is  `nodeclass:not(pone)` should return  236636 -1643 = 234993

what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatsLindh's proposal "*:* -nodeclass:pone" can be shortened to

```
-nodeclass:pone
```

or

```
NOT nodeclass:pone
```

The latter one is a little unusual. NOT has to be in uppercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot @holger-thurow

Comment: Be aware that your first example _may not work_ as expected, unless it's the _only_ or first term in the query. For example, if it's part of an AND or OR term, it'll not behave as you expect. The reason for this is that Solr adds an implicit `*:*` before any query (to start with the set of all documents), exactly so just a negative match by itself will work. This does not happen when it's part of a boolean clause (or in many other cases), and you have to be explicit about adding the set of all documents `*:*` first.

Comment: Sorry, I can not follow you. Could you please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

No idea where you got that syntax from, but to return all documents except for those that have `pone`:

```
*:* -nodeclass:pone
```

In effect, retrieve all documents and subtract the set that matches the query `nodeclass:pone`.

Comment: I accepted other answer because the "NOT" keyword is appropriate in my usecase , as there is wrapper api(written internally) which doesn't allow me to pass "-nodeclass" , Thanks